# Ubuntu проблемы с изображением

Tags: ubuntu

При работе с браузером экран покрыт мелкими точками разных цветов[image: Мелкие точки]
С хромом все намного хуже, при вводе в поисковую строку какого-либо текста, изображение начинает дергаться[image: Дергается изображение]
Кроме того, данные проблемы касаются текстового редактора vscode (остальные не проверял).

Comment: Никаких проблем не замечается если грузиться с nomodeset

Comment: если что nvidia 840m и intel hd graphics 5500

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 но так же проблема проявлялась до обновления на 16, после обновления временно пропадала. Сейчас снова вернулась

Comment: С моником все ок, при подключении 2ого монитора проблема дублируется, так же на win 10 аналогично, только там изображение скачит везде, а не только в браузере

Comment: А если грузиться в Windows? Больше похоже на аппаратную проблему, а не проблему убунты